# Nginx некорректно отдает конкретный файл

Tags: nginx, css

Nginx как-то некорректно отдает один конкретный css файл. Т.е. я вношу изменения в этот файл, пытаюсь его загрузить через браузер, а оказывается, что файл догружен не полностью, т.е. css код в нем есть, но он обрывается где-то в конце файла. Бывало такое?

default.conf

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name ~^(?<tag>.+).(local);
    root /var/www/html/$tag/;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/vm-access.log main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/vm-error.log;

    client_max_body_size 15m;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html;
    }

    location /stc/ {
        rewrite ^/stc/(.*\.)(ver[.0-9]+)(js|css|jpg|gif|png|jpeg)$ /download_static.html?file=$1$3&$args last;
        rewrite ^/stc/(.*\.)(js|css|jpg|gif|png|jpeg)$ /download_static.html?file=$1$2&$args last;
    }

    location ~ \.(php|html)$ {
        fastcgi_pass         127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index        index.html;
        fastcgi_param        SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param        X-Client-Proto  $scheme;
        fastcgi_param        HTTP_X_ISTRUSTEDIP  1;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 240s;
        include              fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /payment/ {
        client_max_body_size 55m;
        fastcgi_pass         127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index        index.html;
        fastcgi_param        SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param        X-Client-Proto  $scheme;
        fastcgi_param        HTTP_X_ISTRUSTEDIP  1;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 240s;
        include              fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/classifier/(?<post_uri>.+)$ {
        include       fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/classifier/index.php;
        fastcgi_param X-CLIENT-PROTO $scheme;
        fastcgi_param CLASSIFIER $post_uri;
    }
}
```

nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте отрубить sendfile. Он, правда, только один раз заставлял меня сделать это, но иногда на его стороне бывают проблемы.

Comment: покажите полный конфиг. и отключите пока open_file_cache

Comment: >>Попробуйте отрубить sendfile.
Отключал, не помогает

Comment: .

    location /stc/ {
        rewrite ^/stc/(.*\.)(ver[.0-9]+)(js|css|jpg|gif|png|jpeg)$ /download_static.html?file=$1$3&$args last;
        rewrite ^/stc/(.*\.)(js|css|jpg|gif|png|jpeg)$ /download_static.html?file=$1$2&$args last;
    }

есть у меня такое подозрение, что это ваш скрипт некорректно отрабатывает.

Comment: Проблему подтверждаю. Помогает только перезапуск nginx. С javascript та же беда.

Comment: Да-да, ранее то же обнаруживал с js, но тогда не придавал этому особого значения. А сейчас приоритет блокирующий.
>> nginx -v
>> nginx version: nginx/1.4.7